# Android MediaPlayer: MP3 streaming works fine via http and in emulator, But causes issues with device

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I'm using the Android MediaPlayer to stream MP3 files via http and it works great in the emulator, But not work on device, and getting errors like this,

`E/MediaPlayer(401): error (1, -2147483648) 04-13 17:23:13.206: W/System.err(401): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1 04-13 17:23:13.226: W/System.err(401):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 401 io exception is actually a HTTP error code for "Authentication failed". That would imply you need a way to enter your basic authentication username and password when it tries to access the stream. Unfortunately this bug report seems to indicate that Android simply doesn't support it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1353

It may be your only option is to remove the access control from the server or find an alternate way to secure it.